# Proving that a set is measurable and has a zero area

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that each of the following sets is measurable and has zero area.
a) A set consisting of a single point.
b) A set consisting of a finite number of points in a plane.
c) The union of a finite collection of line segments in a plane.

All of these seem quite obvious but due to my limited proof writing ability, I cannot move forward. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: What definition of measurable are you working with?

Comment: @CalvinLin The collection of sets in the plane to which an area can be assigned.

Comment: Do you understand why 1. points are measurable and have zero area, 2. lines are measurable and have zero area, 3. finite union of measurable sets with zero area are measurable with zero area?

Comment: @JhbjkMbm Are you sure that is the definition you have of measurable sets (it is quite uncommon I'd say)? If so, then you should have also a domain for your *area* function (otherwise, explain what do you mean by "a set to which an area can be assigned"): check if those subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ belong to that domain!

Comment: @EamesCobb You needed to tell what definitions you were using. Is this an exercise from Apostol's book? I made the following: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089493/proving-that-a-point-is-measurable-and-has-zero-area